# Where can I find ADF test library or source code from c#

Tags: stationarity, cointegration

I would like to test for stationarity in cointegration. I intend to use an augmented dickey fuller test.

However, I need one for c# - either a library or the source code.

Or is your have source in a similar language c, java I can implement.

Thanks

Comment: You can probably roll your own using [Deedle](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/csharpintro.html).

Comment: Thanks, but it is the logic that I need not the data structures

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't find something in C or Java, why not try to call R code within C?

Arguably, this might be a little bit complicated to setup, but it is probably worth the time, as R has good packages featuring many ADF type tests (see for example [urca](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/index.html)), and it seems there are options to embed/call R in C, see for example this discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463437/r-from-c-simplest-possible-helloworld

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that would work BUT will be too slow. This is something that I need to call repeatedly millions of times and the overhead of calling R is too great unfortunately.

Comment: Ah ok, then yes, this solution won't be useful! Btw, if you are doing million times, I guess you are controlling for multiple testing and correcting p-values??